# Saving an array of objects in Core Data swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

So I'm trying to take an array of objects that already exist and then persist the data using core data. I'm slightly confused if I need to map out all of the properties in that custom object, or if I can just save every object directly?

An example would be something like making an entity called CoreDataArrayObj, and then making the custom object an attribute? Or would I need to take that CoreDataArrayObj entity and make all of the properties within the custom object such as string1Prop: String, string2Prop: String, Int1Prop: Int etc...?

Comment: Did you find a solution Bradford?